# Why is a document created even when the required fields are missing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm workingo on a Express, Node.js, and MongoDB project where a user can create a manga document to track it.The required fields are the name and artist fields, which both are Arrays of Strings, because there could be alternative names or multiple artists. The issue is: even when the name and artist fields are blank, the manga document is being created and saved.

Here is my code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const mangaSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: [{ type: String, required: true }],
    artist: [{ type: String, required: true }],
    summary: { type: String },
    chapters: { type: Number },
    comicStatus: { type: String },
    readingStatus: { type: String },
    rating: { type: Number },
    review: { type: String },
    tags: [String],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

mangaSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  const manga = this;
  const requiredFields = ["name", "artist"];
  const missingFields = [];

  requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
    if (!manga[field]) {
      missingFields.push(field);
      console.log("missing fields");
    }
  });

  if (missingFields.length > 0) {
    const error = new Error(
      `Missing required fields: ${missingFields.join(", ")}`
    );
    error.name = "ValidationError";
    return next(error);
  }

  next();
});

export default mongoose.model("Manga", mangaSchema);
```

and here is my the function I use for the post request:

```
async function trackManga(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const manga = new Manga(req.body);
    await manga.save();
    res.status(201).json(manga);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are `name` and `artist` arrays?

Comment: Empty array is truthy

Comment: @Konrad Because there can be multiple alternative names and numerous artists working on one work.